# Save DiagrammeR object to PNG on disc

Tags: r, plot, r-lavaan, diagrammer

I am using the [lavaanPlot-Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaanPlot/vignettes/Intro_to_lavaanPlot.html) to plot my Path Model created with lavaan. Works like a charm. Just to make it easier here is a reproducible example

#### Reproducible Example

```
library(pacman)
p_unload()
p_load(dplyr,lavaan,webshot,lavaanPlot)
model <- 'mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp
          qsec ~ disp + hp + wt'

fit <- sem(model, data = mtcars)
summary(fit)

plot <- lavaanPlot(model = fit, 
                   node_options = list(shape = "box", fontname = "Helvetica"), 
                   edge_options = list(color = "grey"), 
                   coefs = F)

plot
```

However I would like to save the result to a png file on my disc (rather than utilizing some
form of screenshot). Digging in the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaanPlot/lavaanPlot.pdf) I found out that lavaanPlot returns a Diagrammer Object.
I tried to get a png file with three different approaches

#### Approaches

**1. Webshot**
Gives me the error `webshot.js returned failure value: 1`
**2. export_graph**
I found some suggestion how to fix it this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737645/how-to-export-images-of-diagrammer-in-r) on SO, suggesting to use DiagrammeR `export_graph`. However this gives me the following error:

```
Fehler: `export_graph()` REASON:
* The graph object is not valid
```

**3. export_svg**
Additionally I found this suggested solution on [github](https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/330), which I couldnt get to work either. It produces a SVG file for me which I cant open properly

```
# Try 1 using webshot
webshot("Plot_test_webshot.png")

# Try 2 export_graph
plot %>%
  export_graph(file_name = "pic.png",
               file_type = "png")

export_graph(plot,
             file_name = "pic.png",
             file_type = "png")

# Try 3 export_svg
plot %>%
  export_svg() %>%
  charToRaw %>% 
  rsvg_pdf("./path_to_svg_file.svg")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to find a solution in the Github of the maintainer of the package.
Posting this in the hope that anyone in the future looking for a solution will find this

```
# Export Function for lavaanPlot Obtained from github
# https://github.com/alishinski/lavaanPlot/blob/export_plots/R/plotExportFunctions.R

save_png <- function(plot, path){
  DiagrammeRsvg::export_svg(plot) %>%
    charToRaw() %>%
    rsvg::rsvg() %>%
    png::writePNG(path)
}
```

Also on Github there is a [branch](https://github.com/alishinski/lavaanPlot/tree/export_plots) in which this functionality is already included.